# PHP cURL using my IP address instead of the Server?

Tags: php, curl

I want to make a cURL request to a private page where it automatically checks my IP/language to deliver content in that language.

```
        $url = 'https://example.com/';

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        if ($ch === false)
        {
            throw new CurlException('Curl Init return `false`.');
        }

        if ( ! ini_get('open_basedir'))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        }

        if (isset($options['curlHeaders']))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $options['curlHeaders']);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($content === false)
        {
            // there was a problem
            $error = curl_error($ch);
            throw new CurlException('Error retrieving "'.$url.'" ('.$error.')');
        }
        elseif ($content === true)
        {
            throw new CurlException('Unexpected return value of content set to true.');
        }
        return $content;
```

The problem is that the content I get back is always in the same language as my public IP address is. Let's say I want the returned content in English, but it loads in French. The Locale on my computer is in English, the only thing that is French is my IP address.

I have tried it locally and uploaded the code to a server and used a VPN also. I got the same results though.

What am I missing here? Is there any caching when sending cURL requests?

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out I had to set a language header on the cURL settings which solved this issue completely:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.4"));
```